# Reached end of file while parsing....Simple....Beginner Programmer

Tags: java

I do not get what is wrong, It would be great help if anyone would explain it to me so that I (or you) can fix it.

The error that keeps occurring for many of my programs is:

> File: F:\Java Work\Classexample3.java  [line: 40]
>   Error: reached end of file while parsing

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Classexample3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String answer;
        System.out.println("What kind of beverage do you want? (hot or cold)");
        answer = br.readline();

        if (answer.equals("hot")) {
            System.out.println("Please choose an item from the list below:");
            System.out.println("- tea \n- coffee");
            answer = br.readline();

            if (answer.equals("tea")) {
                System.out.println("You have purchased a hot tea:");
            } else if (answer.equals("coffee")) {
                System.out.println("You have purchased a hot coffee");
                answer = br.readline();
            }
        } else if (answer.equals("cold")) {
            System.out.println("Please choose an item from the list below:");
            System.out.println("- bubble tea \n- pop");
            answer = br.readline();
            if (answer.equal("bubble tea")) {
                System.out.println("You have purchased a cold bubble tea");
            } else if (answer.equals("pop")) {
                System.out.println("You have purchased a cold pop");
            } else {
                System.out.println("This item is not on the list");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look how "good" this code looks if you indent it correctly, you can also easily see what the problem is, respectively what the missing "thing" is.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `}` at the end to close the class.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `}` to close the corresponding `public class Classexample3 {`. The error is exactly as it states - the Java compiler expects the class declaration to be closed at some point, but the file ended without doing so.

Answer (score 0):

That error means something wasn't closed like a closing bracket is missing. Looks like the closing bracket for your `Classexample3` class is missing at the bottom of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Once you close your class with an missing `}`, you will a lot of other errors.

First, `br.readline()` should be `br.readLine()`

Second, `answer.equal("bubble tea")` should be `answer.equals("bubble tea")`

These things matter and if you use an IDE, it will make your life as a Java developer a lot easier :)

Comment: I already put 2 brackets at the bottom of the code, So what is wrong?  Do I need to put another one?

Comment: @ComputerProgammerG Without looking at updated code. its hard to tell. Can you edit the question and add the code that you made changes to?